# How to get data from Oracle to send it to statsd or directly into InfluxDB?

Tags: oracle, monitoring, statsd, influxdb

Is there a solution to get some data from Oracle database for further send it to statsd or directly into InfluxDB? I have a lot of sql queries that I need to run periodically for getting some counters. I need an alternative of ORABBIX (zabbix), that have a persistent connection to database, but for stastd/InfluxDB. I want to reduce an connections to database while querying for counters that is in tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is the [cx_Oracle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle) and [InfluxDBClient](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python) you can write a simple Python script that opens all neccessary DB connections, prepares a bunch of SQL statements and repeatedly executes them and feeds them into a influxdb instance.

Basically something along those lines:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import cx_Oracle
ic = InfluxDBClient('vigilante.example.org', 8086, 'collector', 'pw', 'db'

db_dict = {}
for sid in sids:
  db_dict[sid] = cx_Oracle.connect(ORACLE_USER, ORACLE_PASS, sid)

cursor_dict = {}
for (name, c) in config.items():
  cursor = db_dict[c['sid']].cursor()
  cursor.prepare(c['config'])
  cursor_dict[name, c['sid']] = (cursor, c['line'])

def collect(cursor_dict):
  vs = []
  for ((name, sid), (cursor, line)) in cursor_dict:
    rows.execute(cursosr.fetchall())
    if rows:
      vs.append(line.format(sid, *rows[0]))
  if vs:
    ic.write_points(vs, protocol='line')

while True:
  collect(cursor_dict)
  time.sleep(sleep_for_some_dynamically_computed_time)
```

In that example, each SQL statement returns exactly one row and has a influxdb line associated (`c['line']`) which looks like:

```
measurement,db={} col_name1={},col_name2={},col_name3={}
```

You can also add a timestamp to that line - if it is omitted, influxdb uses the current time. Note that this script is long running - and uses prepared statements to avoid wasting DB resources.

Alternatively, if you already have a [collectd](https://collectd.org/) running: there is an [oracle plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Oracle) for collectd. Thus, you could use your existing queries with that plugin and [configure collectd to forward](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Network) the data points [to an influxdb](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/services/collectd/README.md) instance (via UDP, i.e. enable a UDP listening port in the influxdb config).

Answer (score 0):

To sent the data directly into the influxDB:

We can write a java code to insert the data into the influxDB using influxdb-java API

We can create a oracle ojdbc connection, query the data using a sql query and store the result in a ResultSet and create a influxDB connection, read the queried data from the result and store it as point into the influxDB measurement.

We can add the time stamp while creating a point or ignore it , in that case it will automatically take the system date as a time stamp.

### Refer below link for reference: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/influxdb/InfluxDBTest.java